# I have setup items on Sharepoint 2010 team site page to be grouped - need to get rid of the title before the group

Tags: list-view, grouping

How do I take the "title/header" of the column off of the page (tree format) so that just the groups show?  I also need to get the line of a section just under the title to go away.  It is the Column header that is on the view.

For example:

```
INSPECTIONS:                          How we want it: INSPECTIONS
Name                                                   + Fire
                                                         - Standard
+ Headings:  Fire
  + Category:  Standard
```

Is this possible? If so how do I do this?  I have tried changing the web part settings, the view and the tables. The closest I have come is to use the "+" and "-" symbols which I know are not good practices for the metadata.